# How do I use the foreach method in MongoDB to do scraping/API calls without getting blacklisted by sites?

Tags: node.js, web-scraping

I have about 20 documents currently in my collection (and I'm planning to add many more probably in the 100s). I'm using the MongoDB Node.js clients `collection.foreach()` method to iterate through each one and based on the document records go to 3 different endpoints: two APIs (Walmart and Amazon) and one website scrape (name not relevant). Each document contains the relevant data to execute the requests and then I update the documents with the returned data.

The problem I'm encountering is the Walmart API and the website scrape will not return data toward the end of the iteration. Or at least my database is not getting updated. My assumption is that the `foreach` method is firing off a bunch of simultaneous requests and either I'm bumping up against some arbitrary limit of simultaneous requests allowed by the endpoint or the endpoints simply can't handle this many requests and ignore anything above and beyond its "request capacity." I've ran some of the documents that were not updating through the same code but in a different collection that contained just a single document and they did update so I don't think it's bad data inside the document.

I'm running this on Heroku (and locally for testing) using Node.js. Results are similar both on Heroku instance and locally.

If my assumption is correct I need a better way to structure this so that there is some separation between requests or maybe it only does x records on a single pass.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you need to throttle your outgoing web requests. There's a fantastic node module for doing this called [limiter](https://www.npmjs.com/package/limiter). The code looks like this:

```
var RateLimiter = require('limiter').RateLimiter;

var limiter = new RateLimiter(1, 1000);
var throttledRequest = function() {
    limiter.removeTokens(1, function() {
        console.log('Only prints once per second');
    });
};

throttledRequest();
throttledRequest();
throttledRequest();
```